# The smallest number that if multiplied by 2 forms a permutation of itself

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am looking for the smallest number **larger than $0$** which when multiplied by $2$, forms a permutation of itself.

I quickly remembered that the number $142,857$ does that, as well as with all numbers up to $6$ (including). This is the first **cyclic number**, formed by the fraction of $\frac{1}7$

But a computer program quickly showed that the smallest number that does what I asked for is **$125,874$**, because **$125,874*2 = 251,748$**. Interestingly, this number is a permutation of $142,857$ too.

But my question is, how can I find this smallest number **without** a computer program or pre-knowledge, but only with logic and algebra?

Thanks!

Comment: the number must be a multiple of $9$, although I don't know if that helps.

Comment: More significantly, $125+874 = 999$, which is something which occurs in all cyclic numbers: if $x$ is cyclic, then $x = \frac{10^{p-1}-1}p$ where $p$ is a prime for which $10$ is a generator of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: yeah, this I know. but it still doesn't help in approaching this, not that i see anyways. @Mathmo123

Comment: See this solution linked from OEIS sequence [A023086](https://oeis.org/A023086): http://blog.plover.com/math/dd.html